# [react-native]how to realize mask effect

Tags: android, react-native

I want to realize a circle mask on an image, so i have this view:

```
<View style={{width:200,height:200}}>
    <Image source={this.state.photo} resizeMode='cover' style={{width:200,height:200,opacity:0.5}}/>
    <View style={{position:'absolute',left:50,top:50,width:100,height:100,borderRadius:50,opacity:0.8}}>
        <Image source={this.state.photo} resizeMode='cover' style={{width:200,height:200,marginLeft:-50,marginTop:-50}}/>
    </View>
</View>
```

but the mask is a rectangle,not a circle, why?[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue of react-native android. The mask `View` is actually a circle, its the `Image` inside the mask View not honouring the `borderRadius` given to the wrapping `View`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android